# UIWebView Href Link Space Issue

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

## UIWebView Href Link Space Issue

- In My App we have implemented time like "10 min". HTML Side we are
  enabling href link for the "10 min".
- And when we click on 10 min href link, Then in
  **"webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:"** method we are handling time.
- But it is coming up to 10 only, "min" text is not coming because of
  space, If the text is like 10min without space, Then total text is coming.
- But we are showing Dynamic text on Webview. It will come like 10
  min/10 sec/10 hours like that.

How to get 10 min text with space on **"webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:"** method.

We have used the below code.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)mainWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{

  if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    NSLog(@"clicked string:%@",request.URL.absoluteString; 
  }
}
```

Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Using `JS` we can have text of any Element of HTML. you could try `$("a").text()` which will returns you Text on <a> tag. Under WEB-Development what am i doing is, - Fetch necessary Value, - Put it into hidden Field of Form, - and Submit that Form. and Boom. I have required Value into that Hidden Field. and i can do anything with it. Try this Algo in your, might it Help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code resolved my issue.

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>

var anchor = document.getElementById("myLink");
alert(anchor.getAttribute("href")); // Extract link
alert(anchor.innerHTML); // Extract Text
```